# ASP MVC join 2 projects and login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects (App1) and (App1API) that use the same solution to load. I am thinking of authenticating users via JWT through App1API. However, I am unsure of how I can create the controller to log the user in.

Do I reference the login controller from my App1? It uses the default login function that Entity Framework generates. How can I reference that from the API controller? Or is there another way?

THis is my App1 controller for logging in

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

This is the App1API Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login(User user)
        {
            User u = new UserRepository().GetUser(user.UserName);

            if (u == null)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "The user was not found.");

            bool credentials = u.Password.Equals(user.Password);

            if (!credentials) return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                "The username/password combination was wrong.");

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, TokenManagerModel.GenerateToken(user.UserName));
        }
```

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this. You can call your API using Jquery Ajax and store to the token in cookie make a concurrent request. Another way is that use RestClient reference in your App1 project, then call your API using the App1 controller and store token in Session or TempData.

Comment: But I've referenced my API project to the main project and was hoping to inherit classes from the main project.